# live streaming should shifted from 3g to wifi automatically

Tags: android

I am working on android application. I am playing a live stream from IP camera over 3g, Now i want that if my wifi connection is enable and my phone is connected to wifi then stream should automatically shifted to wifi. Please help me out!!!

Stream Type : rtsp

Comment: A few things may help you. How can you detect if wifi is connected? Simply being connected is not good enough, you need to check if you can connect to the server as well. Now you need to establish a new connection and discard the old one.

Comment: Once i used the application call tasker for automating my most of the tasks.they also provide option for switching from 2g/3g to wifi for.so you too can automate this process by searching wifi connection in background and connecting and checking that ,is stream accessible from the wifi or not

Comment: yes, this is a good answer but problem is that when first time my live stream is coming and working fine, When we switch the network its disconnected from network and not able to connect it again. I need it manually to select the channel stream from scratch. Got me?